# Is there a way to automatically generate a TOC or extract a list of "name" tags from a webpage

Tags: html, tags, tableofcontents

I have a webpage which has hundreds of `name` tags in it for each section.

Example:

```
<a name="topic1">1st Topic in series</a>
...
<a name="topic2">2nd Topic in series</a>
...
```

If there an automated way or some online service which can parse the webpage and extract all the `name` tags or better yet generate a HTML Table of Contents based on those `name` tags?

Comment: You won't code your own script to scrap theses specific data ? Otherwise I guess you could find some useful tools here  https://www.bigdatanews.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-extract-text-from-html-document-these-tools-we-can-use

Comment: Unfortunately not my area of expertise, I've inherited some webpages for which I need to create a ToC

Comment: I couldn't find any tool to do it unfortunately so I ended using VIM + excel to extract and parse the tags :)